# Call next() on generator inside of a generator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let gen = testGenerator(),
    foo = true;

console.log( gen.next().value ); //logs 1
console.log( gen.next().value ); // throws 'Uncaught Error: Generator is already running'

function *testGenerator(){
    yield 1;
    if(foo) gen.next(); //I want to immediately advance the generator after the 'yield 2' and run again to 'yield 3'
    yield 2;
    console.log('bar')
    yield 3;
}
```

I want to be able to advance a JS generator to the next stage based on some logic that is encountered while the generator is running (in this example whether 'foo' is true, between 'yield 1' and 'yield 2').

I understand why this code does not work (I can't call 'gen.next()' before the generator is finished running), but I am wondering if there is anyway to immediately call the 'next' step of the generator from inside the generator.

Comment: Rewrite your code to `if (!foo) { yield 2; }` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply rewrite the logic to only perform the second yield if foo is not true.
https://jsfiddle.net/xnxxs20u/

```
 function *testGenerator(){
    yield 1;
    if(!foo) yield 2;        
    console.log('bar')
    yield 3;
}
```